# Module "x" has no attribute "y", creating my own module .py

Tags: python, module

I am trying to create my own module (mi_modulo.py) and move there all the functions that I have defined in my Jupyter Notebook script, so that it looks cleaner.

However, when I am trying to use these functions that I have already moved to the module, I am not able to use them all, and I get the following message:
**module 'mi_modulo' has no attribute 'train4_data_import'**

I have installed Anaconda 3.0 and I am running Python 3.7.0 through Jupyter Notebooks. (Forgive me if the expressions sound awkward, I know a bit of Python, but I am not really into all the installation, software, IDE, etc details.)

```
## mi_modulo.py ##

def train4_data_import(file_name):

    df = pandas.read_excel(file_name)

    force = df["Signal 1"].values[13:]
    acceleration1 = df["Signal 2"].values[13:]
    acceleration2 = df["Signal 3"].values[13:]

    return force, acceleration1, acceleration2

def hola_mundo():
    print("whatever")

## script ##

import pandas
import mi_modulo as mi

mi.hola_mundo()

mi.train4_data_import("Tren4.xlsx")
```

And this is what I get:
(I was going to show an image but I am not sure how to do that with this stackoverflow new form style)

```
whatever

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-69a38929f7e6> in <module>()
      3 mi.hola_mundo()
      4 
----> 5 mi.train4_data_import()

AttributeError: module 'mi_modulo' has no attribute 'train4_data_import'
```

I don't understand why it is able to read one function but not the other.

----------------------------- **EDIT 1** ----------------------------

Doing what U9-Forward suggests:

```
import pandas
from mi_modulo import *

hola_mundo()

train4_data_import("Tren4.xlsx")
```

I get now the following error:

```
whatever


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e1885200beb7> in <module>()
      3 hola_mundo()
      4 
----> 5 train4_data_import("Tren4.xlsx")

NameError: name 'train4_data_import' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you restart the kernel and try again? It can find hola_mundo(), so it should also find train4_data_import. Also make sure to save your mi_modulo first. Maybe you wrote that function and didn't save it.

Comment: Restarting the kernel did the job indeed. Great.
One last thing, when using the module, it seems that I should import in the module itself, all the packages (numpy, pandas...) that I use in that module, is that right?
It is not enough to import them in the Notebook before importing my module, I should also include them in the module.

Comment: yes, you should import pandas in mi_modulo, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Great. I guess I should give you the "right answer" award, but I don't know how to do that, since you didn´t right an "answer" but a comment. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I added my comments as an answer

Comment: I know one more thing, if you restart the kernel still not work, your module might not build right. If you use Jupyter to create a module, you should new a ***Text File*** then write your code save as .py.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In jupyter-notebook, sometimes you need to restart the kernel to import all the unsaved module you have. Also, you need to import all the dependency for the custom module within that module.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you didn't press Ctrl+S or hit the save button on the file, it will probably work if you do that:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Or save button.

then run `script.py` and see it working :-)